# Bicep api management multiple products

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm creating a api managment using bicep files, but when i try to create a products it works only when i created just one in the template. Is there somehow a way to create multiple products related with api management, below is the sample approch

```
resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-08-01' existing = {
  name: 'apim'
}

resource lambdaStoreApi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2020-12-01' = {
  name: 'api'
  parent: apim
  properties:{
    format: 'swagger-json'
    value: loadTextContent('./swagger.json')
    path: 'path'
  }
}

resource product1 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products@2020-12-01' = {
  name: '${apim.name}/product1'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'displayName'
    description: 'description'
    subscriptionRequired: true
    approvalRequired: false
    state: 'published'
  }
}

resource product2 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products@2020-12-01' = {
  name: '${apim.name}/product2'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'displayName'
    description: 'description'
    subscriptionRequired: true
    approvalRequired: false
    state: 'published'
  }
}
```

I am getting error **"Product with the same name already exists"**, but only if I try with more than 1 product.

Is there some way to create with more than one product?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/products?tabs=bicep#productcontractproperties):

> displayName: Product name. string (required).

The `displayName` (product name) also have to be unique. You just need to give this property a unique value:

```bicep
resource product1 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products@2020-12-01' = {
  name: '${apim.name}/product1'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'product1'
    ...
  }
}

resource product2 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/products@2020-12-01' = {
  name: '${apim.name}/product2'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'product2'
    ...
  }
}
```